# How can I display SVG bundled inside a Swift Package?

Tags: ios, swift, svg, swiftui, swift-package

I am trying to display an image bundle inside a Swift Package.

This code `let image = UIImage(named: "image", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)` works when I use `png` image. But when I use a `svg` with the same name (image.svg), the image is `nil`.

This is how I define the resource folder where I save the image in `Package.swift`

```
resources: [
  .process("Resources"),
]
```

Comment: I actually found that the UIImage initialiser you used was the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your file or asset can be in a **xcassets**, add a **xcassets** to **Swift Package** then import your asset there then type your resources like this:

```
resources: [Resource.process("Media.xcassets")]
```

Which **Media.xcassets** carry your asset, then use this code in **Swift Package**:

```
Image("image", bundle: .module)
```

Comment: This is a surprisingly simple solution that I missed out to try. Thank you for pointing out. I tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: It won't work (so fare as I can tell) if you're not using SwiftUI and want access to the image.  macOS provides a `Bundle.image()` function but iOS/tvOS do not.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by placing the asset catalog under "Resources", and including this in the package descriptor:

```
    .target(
        name: "AppResources",
        dependencies: [],
        resources: [
            .process("Resources")]
    ),
```

I could then use an extension of UIImage to access my assets:

```
public extension UIImage {
    static func packagedImage(withName name: String) -> UIImage? {            
        guard let result = UIImage(named: "\(name).png", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil) else {
            return nil
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to append ".png" to the image name.

Comment: In my case there is as the asset names also have ".png".  But you are right than depending on the situation it may not be needed.

Comment: My point is that `UIImage(named:)` doesn't need you to specify the image file extension. It will find the image regardless of its actual extension.

Comment: OK.  That's news to me.  Tests coming up.  ......  Testing shows this not to be the case.

Comment: Yeah, I guess my memory was faulty. I know you don't need an extension when the image is coming from an image set in an asset. But it does seem to be needed if you are accessing a stand-alone image in the resource bundle.